# How do I get youtube video to show on my website

Tags: youtube-api

Homework assignment made a year ago has a youtube movie embedded into the website. Used to work, now getting a 403 error. The code is local on my machine, no one uses it. All other APIs working. API is enabled. The terms have been updated. I'm assuming I have to accept the terms for it to work

Disabled and enabled youtube API, read the terms. Can't find where I need to accept terms. Confirmed no traffic on the API

```
 function getfavesong(favSong) {
   var youtubeURL;
   $.ajax({
     //replace avemaria with favorite song submission from form
     url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=" + favSong + "&key=AIzaSyDykB9j6toAsoXNLuQcM8lJw_Wck_jynPE",
     type: 'GET',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json"
   }).done(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     console.log("youTube video ID: " + data.items[0].id.videoId);
     youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.items[0].id.videoId;

     console.log("youTube complete URL: " + youtubeURL);
     //$("#faveVideo").attr("src",youtubeURL);
   }).done(function () {
     console.log("youTube complete URL: " + youtubeURL);
     $("#faveVideo").attr("src", youtubeURL);
     $('#song_title').text(favSong);
   })`enter code here`
 }
```

I expect to show the video embedded in my website, instead it is a blank box.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a video

```
1   On a computer, go to the YouTube video you want to embed.
2   Under the video, click SHARE Share.
3   Click Embed.
4   From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
5   Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.
```

Embed a playlist

```
1   Sign in to your YouTube account on a computer.
2   On the left side of the page, select the playlist you want to embed.
3   Copy the playlist ID from the URL.
4   Modify the embed code for an individual video by doing the following:
        *   In the place of the video ID (after "embed/"), substitute "videoseries?list=".
        *   Then paste the playlist ID after the "=".
        *   Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.
```

Example:

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLx0sYbCqOb8TBPRdmBHs5Iftvv9TPboYG" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Reference link : https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en
                 https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp

Hope this can help you.